# SPQuery.viewFields does not return specified fields

Tags: 2016, caml-query, camlviewfields, viewfields

I have a list that contains multiple views. I am filtering the view data on the basis of date range using CAML Query. But I don't want all the fields to be return so I used viewFields property of query. But on query execution I am getting only 3 fields.

Any suggestions why it is not returning the fields mentioned in viewFields.

UPDATE :

To create the **CAML** query I am using the list view condition concatenated with my date range condition and then querying the list. To filter the list columns I used **SPView.viewFields** and then used those fields as **SPQuery.viewFields**, because I need colums of that particular view only.